# solo.finishOpenActivities() is always null

Tags: java, android, testing, robotium

I have a test class, but always get a `NullPointerException` in `tearDown()`, anybody knows why?

```
public class LaunchManagerActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LaunchManagerActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public LaunchManagerActivityTest() {
        super(LaunchManagerActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    public void testOne() {

    }

    public void testTwo() {

    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
```

should actually be:

```
 @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
        super.tearDown();
    }
```

The supers teardown will close the activity that got launched but robotium will then get confused as it believes an activity is open, when it tries to do something with it, it is null.

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept all my answers and make mine back!

Comment: I did have some problems in android 2.3.3 when calling super.teardown() and solo.finishOpenedActivities() in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. Only calling one of the 2 let my test run without crashing the whole test process at a random time.